# blender: Bridge Faces/Edge-Loops

Tags: blender

I am running blender 2.60. I would like to know where
the functionality from Mesh -> Scripts -> Bridge Faces/Edge Loops
has gone. Some blogs suggest selecting the faces to bridge and pressing
the F key to bring up a menu from where such operation can be selected
but when I press F in edit mode nothing happens (does not work for me).

Any ideas on the proper way to invoke this functionality in Blender 2.60.

(As a last resort one could always select the edges manually and add the
F key to insert a face one by one which is somewhat longer but I'd like
to know where the original (apparently quicker) functionality is gone).

Thanks,

John Goche

Answer (score 5):

Bridge is now builtin, See menu, Mesh -> Edges -> Bridge.

Answer (score 4):

Bridge is now on [Looptools](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Modeling/LoopTools) addon. Enable the addon, press W on View3D and select Bridge.